# Does the Christian Church's universal expectation of a "Physical Second Coming" constitute a reason for the confusion/delusion in doctrinal concepts?

Tags: biblical-basis

The "Spiritual Second Coming" concept is easily found in the Bible. This is the "restoration" of man's relationship with God as is mentioned in Acts 1:6.

Acts 1:6 KJV

> When they therefore were come together, they asked of him, saying, Lord,will thou at this time restore again the Kingdom to Israel?

This is recognized by most Christians as an event that they refer to as the "Coming of the Holy Spirit".

The "Physical Second Coming" concept which I believe to be unscriptural, persists even though Peter, in His first two sermons in the book of Acts (2:38 and 3:20), clearly illustrated that Jesus comes to believers the Second time "through" the Holy Spirit, Hebrews 9:28.

Acts 2:38

> Then Peter said unto them, Repent, and be baptized every one of you in the name of Jesus Christ for the remission of sins, and ye shall receive the gift of the Holy Ghost.

Acts 3:19-21 ASV

> <sup>**19**</sup> Repent ye therefore, and be converted, that your sins may be blotted out, when the times of refreshing shall come from the presence of the Lord; <sup>**20**</sup> And he shall send Jesus Christ, which before was preached unto you <sup>**21**</sup> whom the heaven must receive until the times of restoration of all things, whereof God spake by the mouth of His holy prophets that have been from of old.

Hebrews 9:28

> So Christ was once offered to bear the sins of many; and unto them that look for him shall he appear the second time without sin unto salvation.

References used as a basis for a "Physical Second Coming concept" are based on an insecure foundation of sand, summarized by using the phrase "these concepts are the interpretation of "Dreams, visions and allegories'".

The addition of a "Physical Second Coming" concept constitutes an addition to scripture, Revelation 22:18.

Revelation 22:18

> For I testify unto every man that heareth the words of the prophecy of this book, If any man shall add unto these things, God shall add unto him the plagues that are written in this book:

Comment: You state "you believe..." and declare it to be based upon "insecure foundations" so what is your question? This seems more like you stating your personal doctrine

Comment: 'Ye men of Galilee, why stand ye gazing up into heaven? this same Jesus, which is taken up from you into heaven, shall so come **in like manner** as ye have seen him go into heaven.' Acts 1:11. Christ's resurrection was bodily, so is his return. So is ours, if we follow him and overcome all, and endure to the end. 'Restore the kingdom to Israel' uses the word _lutrosis_ - it is _short_ of the full restoration of _apolutrosis_ which needs to be studied in depth.

Comment: Matthew 17:12 KJV — But I say unto you, That Elias is come already, and they knew him not, but have done unto him whatsoever they listed. Likewise shall also the Son of man suffer of them.                                                    
                                                              Must the word "likewise" suggest that Jesus suffered exactly as John did?

Comment: So in Acts 1:6 the disciples asked the resurrected Jesus - are you going to "partially restore" (Strong's G600) the kingdom at this time"? Then in Acts 3:21 after the Holy Spirit came Peter said the kingdom has been "fully restored", (Strongs G605).

Comment: You are misunderstanding Acts 3:21.  It says Christ must remain in Heaven until the full restoration.

Comment: Repentance from unbelief is what causes the Father to send Jesus to the individual and this restores all things, Matthew 17:11 KJV — And Jesus answered and said unto them, Elias truly shall first come, and restore all things.

Comment: The doubts raised regarding a partial and complete restoration are resolved by Jesus' statement in Matt 17:11.

Answer (score 1):

The common logic used to work through this problem is as follows:

1. Jesus Christ rose from the dead. (The Gospels, Paul's letters, etc.)
2. The resurrection of Jesus was into a physical body, not just a spiritual one. (Story of doubting Thomas in John 20)
3. All believers will one day rise from the dead.
4. Believers shall be like him (Jesus):

> 20 But our citizenship is in heaven, and from it we await a Savior,
> the Lord Jesus Christ, 21 who will transform our lowly body to be like
> his glorious body, by the power that enables him even to subject all
> things to himself. (Philippians 3:20-21)

5. Believers who have risen from the dead will have physical bodies.

We can see in 1 Thessalonians that still living Christians will meet the once dead Christians, therefore the living Christians with physical bodies will join the Lord, so also the dead will receive new "glorious" bodies.

> 13 But we do not want you to be uninformed, brothers, about those who
> are asleep, that you may not grieve as others do who have no hope. 14
> For since we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so, through
> Jesus, God will bring with him those who have fallen asleep. 15 For
> this we declare to you by a word from the Lord,[d] that we who are
> alive, who are left until the coming of the Lord, will not precede
> those who have fallen asleep. 16 For the Lord himself will descend
> from heaven with a cry of command, with the voice of an archangel, and
> with the sound of the trumpet of God. And the dead in Christ will rise
> first. 17 Then we who are alive, who are left, will be caught up
> together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air, and so
> we will always be with the Lord. 18 Therefore encourage one another
> with these words. (1 Thessalonians 4:13-18)

The causes of the confusion are many: Satan's lies, people's impatience or fears, and immaturity. The church has not yet reached full maturity. The answers to many of these mysteries await the time when the Church reaches maturity, after the seals have all been removed from the scroll of Revelation and all is revealed.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, I think that a reason for the doctrinal disagreements among God's people is the result of Divine Judgment.

The Bible exalts God in Romans 3:4, to the exclusion of "All" men.

> Ro 3:4 God forbid: yea, let God be true, but every man a liar; as it is written, That thou mightest be justified in thy sayings, and mightest overcome when thou art judged.

When a Christian sins willfully ( a condition that prevails in Christian denominations) God delivers them over to delusion (2 Thess 2:11) so that the Wicked sin can be judged (2 Thess 2:12) and removed from their lives, to prevent the Christians themselves from being condemned along with unbelievers, 1 Cor 11:32.

> 2 Th 2:8 And then shall that Wicked be revealed, whom the Lord shall consume with the spirit of his mouth, and shall destroy with the brightness of his coming:

> 2 Th 2:10 And with all deceivableness of unrighteousness in them that perish; because they received not the love of the truth, that they might be saved. 11 And for this cause God shall send them *"strong delusion"*, that they should believe a lie: 12 (ASV) that they all might be judged who believed not the truth, but had pleasure in unrighteousness.

> 1 Co 11:32 But when we are judged, we are chastened of the Lord, that we should not be condemned with the world.

Many intelligent Christians differ drastically concerning doctrine. While this can be excused as simple intellectual differences, based on growth and experience, I think it goes further than that.

These differences are the result of divine correction as God intentionally sends delusion to people because of sinful conduct.

> 1Ki 22:20 And the LORD said, Who shall persuade Ahab, that he may go up and fall at Ramothgilead? And one said on this manner, and another said on that manner.
> 21 And there came forth a spirit, and stood before the LORD, and said, I will persuade him.
> 22 And the LORD said unto him, Wherewith? And he said, I will go forth, and I will be a lying spirit in the mouth of all his prophets. And he said, Thou shalt persuade him, and prevail also: go forth, and do so.
> 23 Now therefore, behold, the LORD hath put a lying spirit in the mouth of all these thy prophets, and the LORD hath spoken evil concerning thee.

Comment: This also reads just like a personal interpretation which doesn't hold up to scrutiny.

Comment: I suggest you be more careful as to whom you (publicly, on the global internet) condemn to judgment and delusion. With what measure you meet out to others, will be meted again unto yourself. As it will be to all of us.